# .textContent property updating differently in two event listeners?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner at JS attempting to build a calculator for practice/learning. I've managed to cover the basic click functionality and now in the process of adding keyboard input. I'm having issues mimicking the behavior of a iOS calculator where once the operator key is pressed, the display area 'holds' operand 1 and then begins displaying operand 2 on the next number key press.

My issue lies in that I've managed to capture this behavior under my .number_key click handler, but not my keyboard input handler. In the keyboard input, it captures the operator string instead of clearing it, then concatenating e.key. i.e. it will show +44 for the second operand, whereas the click behavior will begin the new string without the operator. Even though the code is the same, and the only difference is the type of event, why is the behavior different? I feel I am overlooking something critical but can't identify it.

source code:

```
// declaring variables

let n1;
let n2;
let operator;
let pressed = [];
let keydown = [];

//selectors

const calcDisplay = document.querySelector('#display');
const calcKeys = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons');

//selectors + event listeners

const numberClicked = document.querySelectorAll('.number_key').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (pressed.slice(-1) == '+' || pressed.slice(-1) == '-' || pressed.slice(-1) == '*' || pressed.slice(-1) == '÷') {
      calcDisplay.textContent = '' + e.target.textContent;
      pressed.push(e.target.textContent);
    } else {
      calcDisplay.textContent += e.target.textContent;
      pressed.push(e.target.textContent);
    }
  });
});

const operatorClicked = document.querySelectorAll('.operator').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    n1 = calcDisplay.textContent;
    operator = e.target.textContent;
    pressed.push(e.target.textContent);
    console.log(n1, operator);
  });
});

const equalsClicked = document.querySelector('#equals').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  n2 = calcDisplay.textContent;
  console.log(n2);
  calcDisplay.textContent = calculate(n1, n2, operator);
});

// clear display
document.querySelector('#clear').addEventListener('click', () => {
  clear();
});

// operation is performed

const calculate = (n1, n2, operator) => {
  if (operator === '+') {
    return parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2);
  } else if (operator === '-') {
    return parseInt(n1) - parseInt(n2);
  } else if (operator === '*') {
    return parseInt(n1) * parseInt(n2);
  } else if (operator === '÷' || operator === '/') {
    return parseInt(n1) / parseInt(n2);
  }
};

// clear function
const clear = () => {
  calcDisplay.textContent = '';
  n1 = '';
  n2 = '';
  operator = '';
  pressed = [];
};

// listen for keyboard input
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  acceptableKeys = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '-', '*', '/'];
  if (e.key in acceptableKeys) {
    calcDisplay.textContent += e.key;
    pressed.push(e.key);
  }

  //mimic 'operatorClicked behavior'
  else if ((e.shiftKey && e.key === '+') || (e.shiftKey && e.key === '*') || e.key === '/' || e.key === '-') {
    n1 = calcDisplay.textContent;
    operator = e.key;
    pressed.push(e.key);
    console.log(n1, operator);
    if (pressed.slice(-1) == '+' || pressed.slice(-1) == '-' || pressed.slice(-1) == '*' || pressed.slice(-1) == '/') {
      calcDisplay.textContent = '' + e.key;
      pressed.push(e.key);
    }
  }

  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    n2 = calcDisplay.textContent;
    console.log(n2);
    calcDisplay.textContent = calculate(n1, n2, operator);
  }

  if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
    calcDisplay.textContent = calcDisplay.textContent.slice(0, -1);
  }
})
```

full code with HTML/CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/icycold/Laq1ers6/201/

I can 'fix' the issue by setting `calcDisplay.textContent = '' + e.key;` to `calcDisplay.textContent = '';` however, then the first operand isn't displayed until the next one is entered and is instead cleared fully. I would want it to behave exactly as when I use clicks.

I'd appreciate any and all help as this entry-level project has taught me a lot via trail/error.

Comment: I see a few issues. You're using `in` to check `acceptableKeys` which is wrong - that's not how you search an array for a value. Your `acceptableKeys` also includes `'+'` and operators, so it looks like you're intentionally trying to show the plus character (even though I don't think that code is running since `in` is invalid). You're also very intentionally adding the `+` character on the line you've called out with the check `pressed.slice(-1) == '+'` - I don't understand why you're intentionally checking for and adding the `+` operator while also asking how to not show the `+` operator.

Comment: Split out into smaller functions so as to not repeat as much and make it a bit less confusing!  You can use [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if a character is in a string.  [cleaned up a bit](https://jsfiddle.net/j1ryqtg3/1/)

Comment: @AndyRay I see what you're getting at. I was essentially 'allowing' + to be a possible character in my display, and since in the click handler I didn't (incorrectly) iterate over an acceptableKeys array I wasn't seeing that as a problem. Since I have not quite gotten to 'state based' JS which is what I assume future knowledge about would make a calculator more robust - the logic I was under was that checking for the operator 'initiated' the 'ready for second operand' phase of the calculation. On top of the repeated and messy code like James pointed out - I got lost in my own logic.

Comment: @James That is so much cleaner, wow. I noticed it felt very repetitive and was embarrassed about posting on here to be fair. I noticed your usage of passing in the e.key into number/operator pressed constants - I didn't think to use the event that way, and it cleans the code a lot. Also took note of simply providing a long string such as '0123456789' then running includes on it.

As a follow up question, in lines 14-20. How come once the check for the operator string value happens, the textContent does not immediately go blank and instead "holds" the first operand?  That still stumps me.

Comment: Keep in mind that numberPressed only runs when a number is pressed.  So you enter a number, press an operator, and then when you start typing another number it clears the screen then.

Comment: @James I see it now!! Thank you so much. Comparing it to lines 85-88 I see why your solution has the intended behavior. I'll study it further and see if I can reproduce it on my own.